# Players Health getting recuded only once when attacked

Tags: c#, unity

I made a game in Unity 2D

Issue: I have made some spikes and other aliens, which decreases the players health if they come in contact. The health only decreases once instead of getting decreased every time player move or till the time player is in contact with the spike/alien.
have tagged player as "player" and alien and other things as "deadly"

public class Explode : MonoBehaviour {

```
public BodyPart bodyPart;
public int totalParts;

private Player player;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () { 
    player = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Player> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target){
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
        LifeMeter script = player.GetComponent<LifeMeter>();
        script.life();
    }

}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D target){
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Deadly") {
        LifeMeter script = player.GetComponent<LifeMeter>();
        script.life();
    }

}

public void OnExplode(){
    Destroy (gameObject);

    var t = transform;

    for (int i = 0; i < totalParts; i++) {
        BodyPart clone = Instantiate(bodyPart, t.position, Quaternion.identity) as BodyPart;
        clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.right * (Random.Range (-50, 50)));
        clone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.up * Random.Range(100, 400));
    }

    GameObject go = new GameObject ("ClickToContinue");
    ClickToContinue script = go.AddComponent<ClickToContinue> ();
    script.scene = Application.loadedLevelName;
    go.AddComponent<DisplayRestartText> ();

}
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add what's in script.life()?

Comment: This question is way too localized

Comment: The Question wasnt answered, it was just put on HOLD

Comment: Whatever this question is, it's not a duplicate. The question was a duplicate of is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Unity, but it seems you should implement

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html

and

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html

as well. These functions are called each frame instead of only the first frame there is a contact.

In fact, you should probably only implement these as otherwise on the first frame you'd get 2 life reductions instead of only one.